# Trouble with Calculating Values for a Nested For Loop

Tags: c++

I need to prints asterisks in the following way:

xxxxxxx
_xxxxx
__xxx

(7, 5, 3)

or

xxxxxx
_xxxx
__xx

(6, 4, 2)

There is an input for the top number of asterisks and an input for the number of rows. There must never be less than two asterisks on the bottom row.

I realize that this requires a nested `for` loop.

I have the following code:

```
  for (rows = 1; rows < ((toprow / 2) + (toprow % 2)); rows++)
    {
      for ()
      cout << endl;                                    
    }
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out the inner `for` loop.

Comment: continually subtract 2 from the first number then use an if statement checking if its greater than or equal to two

Comment: What about the formatting, though? The lagging spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (rows = 1; rows < ((toprow / 2) + (toprow % 2)); rows++)
  {
    if(rows <= maxrows)
      {
        // first the leading underscores
        for (int k=1; k<rows; ++k)
          cout << "_";

        // then the asterisks
        for (int k=1; k <= toprow - 2*rows + 2; ++k)
          cout << "*";
        cout << endl;                                    
      }
  }
```

**EDIT:** your outer loop does not iterate over the correct number of rows. It should be this:

```
for (int rows = 1; rows <= (toprow / 2); rows++)
  ...
```

Comment: Hmm...I'm trying this, but I'm not getting any output.

Comment: Looks like if the input is an even number of rows, it doesn't print the last row (**).

Comment: I needed that extra bit to include the last row for odd rows. With your edit, for `toprow = 5` and `rows = 2` it's only printing 5 asterisks, for example. EDIT: Nevermind, you're correct. I forgot the `=`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
int initial = 7;
int copy = initial;
int rows = 3;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    std::cout << std::string(initial - copy, ' ')
              << std::string(copy, '*') << std::endl;
    copy -= 2;
}
```

This is assuming that rows is provided as a valid input.

Answer (score 0):

Use this C code as a reference. It will print upto the number of rows or when last row has starts less than 2, whichever is earlier.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
    //topstar have the number of stars in top row
    int row=7;
    int topstar=7;
    int i,j,k,l,last;

    for(i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
    //last contain the number of stars in last row
    last=topstar - 2*i;

    if(last<2)
     break;

     for(k=0;k<i;k++)
       printf("_");
    for(j=0;j<last;j++)
       printf("*");
    for(l=0;l<i;l++)
       printf(" ");
       printf("\n");
   }
  return 0;
}
```

Output of this code is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
spaces = 0;
asterix = toprow;
for (rows = 1; rows < ((toprow / 2)  + (toprow % 2)) && asterix > 1; rows++)
    {
      for (i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
        print -; 

      for (i = 0; i < toprow; i++)
        print *;

      println  

      spaces+=2;
      asterix -=2; 

    }
```